# In Chrome Event Pages, can I use the Alarms API to run code at specified intervals, while also ignoring code I want to run only once?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

As I understand it, in Chrome Extensions, Event Pages go inactive after a short period of time to free up memory in Chrome. Whereas Background Pages run all the time. I'd like to code my extension to use Event Pages and allow my extension to not be a memory hog.

Since the event page goes inactive, I am unable to use setInterval to periodically run code in the background. The recommended solution is to use the [`chrome.alarms`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/alarms.html) API as seen here:

```
chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function(alarm) {
    if (alarm.name == 'name-of-alarm') {
        // Do something...
        testFunc();
    }
});

// Create the alarm:
chrome.alarms.create('name-of-alarm', {
    periodInMinutes: 10
});
```

My issue is that when this code wakes up my event page, it runs ALL of the code inside it and not just the `testFunc()` I specified. I have code in my event page that I only want to run once (when the browser starts or when the extension is reloaded/updated). The alarms API does not seem to be fit for what I'm trying to do.

What's the best way to handle this while keeping my event page an event page?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onStartup